# CodeIgniter: 404 Page Not Found ( In Hosting Server )

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

note : everything going well when I try in Localhost.

So I have a problem when I want to call my do_login controller in my login form.

this is my controller :

```
<?php 

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Do_login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('login_model', '', TRUE);
    }

    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required|callback_check_database');


            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                    $this->load->view('admin/login_view'); 
            }
            else
            {
                    redirect('home', 'refresh');
            }       
    }

    public function check_database($password)
    {
            $email = $this->input->post('email', TRUE);

            $result = $this->login_model->check_login($email, $password);

            if($result)
            {
                    $sess_array = array();
                    foreach($result as $row)
                    {
                            $sess_array = array(
                                'user_id' => $row->user_id,
                                'email' => $row->email
                            );
                            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
                    }
                    return TRUE;
            }
            else 
            {
                    $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Email / Password salah');
                    return FALSE;
            }
    }

}

?>
```

this is my view :

```
<?php
      $attributes = array('class' => 'form-signin', 'id' => 'myform');
      echo form_open('do_login', $attributes);
 ?>
```

When I try it in Localhost, everything going well and smooth.
But when I try in my web server, everytime I submit the login form, I directed into 404.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Make sure your file names start with an Uppercase letter. So your Do_login file, should be Do_login.php (Capital D)

Comment: what is your base url at config.php? and which 404 you redirected? CI or server default.

Comment: @Craig : of course all my controller file begins with Uppercase letter

Comment: $config['base_url'] check what is written in config.php file

Comment: @ShaifulIslam : I already set my base_url in right format at config.php, CI 404

Comment: can you please show us your config.php file

Comment: @saty : this is my base_url in config.php http://tera.norwinskitchenware.com/norwin/

Comment: @saty : check it http://tera.norwinskitchenware.com/norwin/

Comment: yaa url is open bye this is not the contain of cofig.php file

Comment: @saty : sorry, I didnt get it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77507/discussion-between-tableman-and-saty).

Answer (score 0):

Check your file names Because  it happens with me that different case file name was worked on localhost but not on server.
So check it once.